# Why compiler cannot find 'axios'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors, axios

I already download 'axios' but compiler return this code.. every single time.. :(

> "Module not found: Can't resolve 'axios' in 'C:\react-app\src\lib\api'"

this code is one of a file that I call axios..

```
import axios from 'axios';

const client = axios.create();

export default client;
```

Comment: Could you share your package.json file?

Comment: did you installed in this way npm install axios

Comment: Check your node_modules folder in your project folder(src), there should be axios folder. if it does not exist, that means you did not install it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as there are some missing data I wont assume nothing, let's start by

1.- first you need to have an npm project create one by:

```sh
$ npm init -y
```

that will create a package.json with default values.

2.- install `axios` and `axios-es6-class`

```sh
$ npm i axios axios-es6-class
```

`axios-es6-class` is a npm module I created that allows you to use `axios` as a modern class

```js
import {Api} from "axios-es6-class";

export class UserApi extends Api {
  constructor (config) {
    super(config);

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.register = this.register.bind(this);
  }

   register (userModel) {
      return this.post("/endPoint", {...userModel})
       .then(this.success)
       .catch(this.error);
   }

      login (credentials {
      return this.post("/endPoint", {...credentials})
       .then(this.success)
       .catch(this.error);
   }
}

.....

const api = new UserApi(AxiosRequestConfig);

api.register(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

To use axios like that, you should install it using npm or yarn:

npm:

```
npm install axios
```

yarn:

```
yarn add axios
```

If you already installed it, reinstall it by removing the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

[More information](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).